# How to print an array of items using list tag and angular js in a way so that they are displayed with three rows and three columns

Tags: angularjs

Im trying to print out a list of names so that on the page they would be in a grid type look.
What I have so far.

```
<html ng-app>
<head> <script src="angular.js"></script></head>
<body ng-init= "names=['Bob', 'Bill', 'Sarah', 'Robert', 'Sam', 'Jill', 'Dave', 'Larry', 'Jack']">
<ul ng-repeat="firstname in names">
<li>{{firstname}}</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

It should print out like this:
Bob, Bill, Sarah
Robert, Sam, Jill
Dave, Larry, Jack

Comment: what error do you get? If the display is not correct, you have to adjust it with css

Answer (score 0):

Move the ng-repeat to the li...

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="firstname in names">{{firstname}}</li>
</ul>
```

And you can turn them into inline blocks with CSS...

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    min-height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    border: solid 1px black;
    margin: -1px;
}
```

[**Demo - Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HeYv7/)